# Close Navigation Drawer After Click

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How do you close the `NavigationDrawer` after clicking to open a new `Fragment`. I have tried a few things but just can't get it to work

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, BookAFragment.newInstance())
                .commit();
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_strains) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Book A Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        BookAFragment fragment = new BookAFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        return true;

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_recipes) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Book B Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        BookBFragment fragment = new BookBFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        return true;

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: If your execution enters either of the `if`s, it's returning before the `closeDrawer()` call. Either call `closeDrawer()` in each `if`, or change your code to only `return` at the end of `onNavigationItemSelected()`. Also, you don't need to call `findViewById()` for the DrawerLayout again.

Comment: Use this: `drawerLayout.closeDrawers();`

Comment: You are doing `DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);` twice.